# How to set default number format to include thousand separator (,)

Tags: excel, excel-2016

Excel uses `"0.00"` as its current default Number format. I know Excel format window gives the option to add thousand separator (,) to selected cells. Is there a way to include the thousand separator as the default Number format in Excel, i.e. `"#,##0.00"`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Setting the DEFAULT options for Excel seems a bit tricky at first .. the options are limited:

If you go File => Options
Under General tab, and down to "When creating new workbooks" .. it gives you options for font .. but unfortunately, nothing for Number format  :(

You could do it via a macro, or by setting up an Excel template.

The Template option might work best:

```
1) Open a new workbook. 
2) set all your formats for all cells to the
  "default" you want (ie select entire sheet, change number format ..)
3) Click "save as" and select "Excel Template (*.xltx)"
```

Once saved, when you open a new workbook, you just select your template as your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Check the custom format, you might find it here:

[image]

Just replace the according space character by the dot or the comma, as you prefer.